# Copying wiremock files from my local to Docker container using docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose, wiremock

I need copy my local files "Wiremock files" into wiremock container using docker-compose.yml.

the path of my files is:

1. /src/test/resources/wiremock-docker/wiremock/__files
2. /src/test/resources/wiremock-docker/wiremock/mapping

I generate the next Wiremock image in my docker-compose

```
wiremock:
image: '${WIREMOCK_IMAGE}'
volumes:
- ./src/test/resources/wiremock-docker/wiremock/__files/:/home/wiremock/__files
- ./src/test/resources/wiremock-docker/wiremock/mappings:/home/wiremock/mappings
```

`exposedPorts: [8080/tcp]
  attachStdin: true
  attachSterr: true
  dnsSearch: [losthost]
  alwaysPull: false
  portBindings: [8585->8080/tcp]`

I tried using volumes, but the files inside the folders "__files" and "mapping" didnt copy in the image

**volumes:**

```
- ./src/test/resources/wiremock-docker/wiremock/__files/:/home/wiremock/__files
- ./src/test/resources/wiremock-docker/wiremock/mappings:/home/wiremock/mappings**
```

I know that using Dockerfile works:

```
FROM rodolpheche/wiremock

EXPOSE 8585 8080 8081

COPY wiremock /home/wiremock
```

but in this case I need to copy the files from the docker-compose

Answer (score 2, accepted):

docker-compose does only mount volumes not copy them into the image